# Should i use Laravel Passport or JWT resource?

Tags: laravel

I know passport uses oAuth, but my question is.. is it better to use Passport for Auth (Login and Register) or should i use jwt for login and register and Passport for external API requests... or use passport for both (User API and Login/AUTH)

Now i'm programming a SPA website with laravel and VueJs 2, i'm stuck in this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Laravel Passport does, in fact, use JWT so comparing "JWT vs Passport" is kind of wrong.

You can use Laravel Passport for everything you mentioned - logging in, registering (not built-in in Passport but easy to add) and protecting external API requests.